# move_uploaded_file() return false

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a big problem i can't resolve ..

I have to upload multiple file, so that's what i use

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           Seleziona uno o più file<br />
            <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
            <input type="hidden" name="pathFileToUpload" value="<?php echo $dirToScan ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Carica file" />
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
$target_dir = $_POST['pathFileToUpload'];
$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
      if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath,$target_dir)) 
            echo "<script>alert('upload')</script>";
 else 
        echo "<script>alert('Not uploaded')</script>";
 }
```

So,what i can see is that the file is correctly passed to the server, so $tmpFilePath contain the temporary path of the file in php, and that $target dir is correct, but the upload goes wrong every time and move_uplaoded_file return false.

I tried too to replace the $target_dir with some path that i'm sure they exist, but nothing.

And the function has the permission to move the file in the server, because first when there was only single upload file it works perfectly ...

PS: I already searched in the forum, but don't found anything that's my case, i try many solutions found as using $_SERVER['Document_root'].'uploads/'  but already nothing ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`move_uploaded_file` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) should receive as a second parameter the name of the file you want to create:

```
bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

In your code it looks like `$target_dir` variable is only the name of the **folder**, and not the complete destination (the folder + the new file to create), otherwise you are telling `php` to **override** the directory, and it doesn't really make any sense.

You can use the original name of the file that you got from the user:

```
$target_dir = $_POST['pathFileToUpload'];
$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $name = basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"][$i]);
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $target_dir . "/" . $name)) 
        echo "<script>alert('upload')</script>";
    else 
        echo "<script>alert('Not uploaded')</script>";
}
```

Or give the file a new random name.